# Split Multiple Line values into Column using sed/awk between Pattern markers

Tags: awk, sed, split, multiline

I need to split the rows between the pattern markers1 and 2 into columns.
What i notice is that the Sed indicates a failure to split the columns. Could someone help?.

```
StartPattern1
AAA\n
BBB\n
CCC\n
EndPattern
Some text
StartPattern2
XXX\n
YYY\n
ZZZ\n
MMM\n
NNN\n
EndPattern2
```

Result Needed from sed/awk:

```
StartPattern1
AAA\tBBB\tCCC
End Pattern1
StartPattern2
XXX\tYYY\tZZZ\tMMM\tNNN\n
EndPattern2
```

Comment: Is the `\n` new line or the literal text, same with `\t`?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
cat file
StartPattern1
AAA
BBB
CCC
EndPattern
Some text
StartPattern2
XXX
YYY
ZZZ
MMM
NNN
EndPattern2
```

```
awk '/StartPattern/ {f=1;print;next} f && ! /EndPattern/ {printf "%s%s",$0,(f?"\t":RS)} /EndPattern/ {f=0;print "\n"$0;next}' file
StartPattern1
AAA     BBB     CCC
EndPattern
StartPattern2
XXX     YYY     ZZZ     MMM     NNN
EndPattern2
```

---

Here is another one:

```
awk '/^Start/{f=g=1} /^End/{f=0;print "\n"$0} f {printf "%s%s",$0,(g--==1?RS:"\t")}' file
StartPattern1
AAA     BBB     CCC
EndPattern
StartPattern2
XXX     YYY     ZZZ     MMM     NNN
EndPattern2
```